# Error in android project

Tags: android, r.java-file

[image]

As you can see,all the android projects in my workspace is now showing cross sign.The R.java file is not generated.It was fine last night and in the morning I cleaned my workspace then suddenly the errors have showed up.I tried everything,cleaning again,restarting eclipse.But no luck.Please help.

This is my SDK:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked projects? What they are missing ? What is the version of your ADT ?

Comment: how about clean and build??? did you build after clean?

Comment: do you updated or ignored some ADT updation ??

Comment: the R.java file is missing.I mean it is not generating.

Comment: I restarted the eclipe and retarted the machine also.no luck....goshhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!!I have a project delivary today

Comment: do you updated or ignored some ADT updation ??

Comment: select one project first clean it then build may it work

Comment: R.java is missing that means your resources folder is missing something..just try to check that..also you can try..project->rightclick->properties->fix project properties or ->add support library

Comment: @Sree posted my sdk..pls check..

Comment: @MeenalSharma cant find "fix project properties".

Comment: why u dot do't update 22.6.2 . Do it all will become ok

Comment: @Sree..ok....I am doing that...thanks mate..

Comment: ohh sorry..its project->rightclick->android tools->fix project properties

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem solved by the following steps,

Solution

- Make sure that anything the R. links to is not broken. Fix all errors in your XML files. If anything in the ADKs are broken, R will not regenerate.
- If you somehow hit something and created import android.R in your activity, remove it.
  Run Project -> Clean. This will delete and regenerate R and BuildConfig.
- Make sure Project -> Build Automatically is ticked. If not, build it manually via Menu -> Project -> Build Project .
- If it doesn't work, delete everything inside the /gen/ folder
  -If it still doesn't work, try right-clicking your project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.
  -Check your *.properties files (in the root folder of your app folder) and make sure that the links in there are not broken.
  -Right-click your project > properties > Android. Look at the Project Build Target and Library sections on the right side of the page. Your Build Target should match the target in your AndroidManifest.xml. So if it's set to target 17 in AndroidManifest, make sure that the Target Name is Android 4.2. If your Library has an X under the reference, remove and re-add the library until there's a green tick. This might happen if you've moved a few files and folders around.

What to do if R doesn't regenerate

- Check that Android SDK Build-tools is installed. Window->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Android SDK Build-tools
- Make sure when you update the Android SDK Tools, you also update the Android SDK Platform-tools and Android ASK Build-tools. Build fails silently if they don't match.
- If you can't find the issue, right click /gen/ -> Restore from local history... -> tick R.java -> click Restore. This doesn't solve the problem, but it will clear out the extra errors to make the problem easier to find.