# Error in android projects -part 2

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

4 hours now.And my struggle continues.I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284488/error-in-android-project) at morning.One of my fellow friend here suggested to update the sdk.I did that.After that eclipse was asking to update the adt plug-in.I downloaded the latest version from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).But whenever I try to install it from help->install new software->add,a new error occurs():[image][image: refer the image below]

I tried everything.I consult stack overflow and find to run eclipse as administrator.Still couldn't find a solution.I am using eclipse Helios and my jdk is up-to-date.

Comment: I think you need to update eclipse first.In help menu select check for updates. I don't know whether it work or not but give it a try

Comment: Generally when this happens, it is really hard to solve it. Better option is download a fresh eclipse and install adt init and start using it.

Comment: @Kedarnath...bro...u break my heart

Comment: @NARESHREDDY...check for updates showing "no updates found" :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ADT 22.6.2 (March 2014)

**Dependencies:**

- Java 1.6 or higher is required.
- Eclipse Indigo (Version 3.7.2) or higher is required.
- This version of ADT is designed for use with SDK Tools r22.6.2. If
  you haven't already installed SDK Tools r22.6.2 into your SDK, use
  the Android SDK Manager to do so.

**CONCLUSION:** `ADT 22.6.2` is not compatible with `Eclipse Helios`.

**SOLUTION:**

Download ADT 22.3.0 (October 2013) for Eclipse Helios.

---

### ADT 22.3.0 (October 2013)

**Dependencies:**

- Java 1.6 or higher is required.
- Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required.
- This version of ADT is designed for use with SDK Tools r22.3. If you
  haven't already installed SDK Tools r22.3 into your SDK, use the
  Android SDK Manager to do so.

**REFERENCE:** [Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: my sdk is 22.6.So is it compatible with sdt 22.3??

Comment: my sdk is 22.6.So is it compatible with sdt 22.3?? - NO, `This version of ADT is designed for use with SDK Tools r22.3.` So revert to old SDK.

Comment: Yes I reverted to the old one.